# Showing that a matrix is invertible by factorisation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $P_5$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq$ 5 over $Q$.

$P_5 = {a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5: a_i \in Q}$ and let $D: P_5 \longrightarrow P_5$ be the linear map $D(\alpha) = \frac{d \alpha}{dx}$. By factorising the expression $D^6 - Id$ show that $D^4+D^2+Id: P_5 \longrightarrow P_5$ is invertible and write down its inverse.

I am not quite sure how I can show that $D^4+D^2+Id$ is invertible but I tried factorising the given expression in the following way:

$$ \begin{align*} D^6 - Id &= D^6 - Id^6\\ &= (D-Id) (D^5 + D^4Id + D^3Id^2 + D^2Id^3 + DId^4 + Id^5)\\ &= (D-Id)(D^5 + D^4 + D^3 + D^2 + D + Id)\\ &= (D-Id) (D^3(D^2+D+Id) + D^2 + D+Id)\\ &= (D-Id) (D+Id) (D^4+D^2+Id)\\ &= (D^2 - Id) (D^4 + D^2 + Id)\end{align*} $$

and now I am not sure what to do next

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I split your chain equation across several lines for easier reading.  However I think $I$ rather than $Id$ would make more sense to represent the identity matrix.

Comment: @hardmath But $D$ here is a linear *map*, so $\mathrm{Id}$ here makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}$
Hint: $D^6(\alpha) \equiv 0_{P_5} \forall \alpha \in P_5$ since differentiating polynomial $\alpha \in P_5$ having degree $\le 5$ gives zero.

From the factorisation of $D^6 - \Id$, we see that $(D^4 + D^2 + \Id)(\Id - D^2) = \Id$.  Therefore, the operator $D^4 + D^2 + \Id$ is invertible with inverse $\Id - D^2$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense now!

Answer (score 3):

In a ring $R$, $u \in R$ is invertible if $u v = v u = 1$, for some $v \in R$.

Here $R$ is the ring (under composition) of $\mathbb{Q}$-linear operators on $P_5$, $u = D^4 + D^2$, and $1_R = Id$.  Can you see what $D^6$ does to $P_5$?  If so, you will see that you have found the $v$.

Comment: Thank you! D^6 will become 0 in this case